# How do I grant access to Azure Kubernetes service?

Tags: azure-aks

I'm trying to grant a single user access to a particular AZ AKS service.   I've got in and found his name and assigned him to the role `Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Role` but he still can't see the single service.   On a whim, I also tried the `Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role` but the results were the same.

We're using AD federated with our company.

Comment: define `cant see a single service` please?

Comment: When the user goes to the "Kubernetes Services" from the portal, nothing is listed.

I'd like the user to see the specific service, but not be able to create anything new, etc.   For the service itself, I'd like to have the user to able to kubectl apply to it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to grant reader role on the resource to the user on top of the roles you've given him

Comment: Thanks, that did it!